# SyntaxError: Unterminated string in JSON at position 52428390 when JSON.parse() result of google sheets api call

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a Google Apps Script web app, and i need to retrieve data from a spreadsheet.

```
function testOther() {
  var spreadsheetId = "spreadsheetID";
  var range = "'PERMISSIONS'!A1:G";
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheetId + "/values/" + range + "?majorDimension=ROWS&valueRenderOption=FORMULA";

  var request = {
    method: "get",
    url: url,
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, request);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

The result in string looks like this, and values can contain hundreds of thousands results:

```
{
  "range": "PERMISSIONS!A1:G491462",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "ID",
      "Title",
      "Type",
      "Email",
      "Role",
      "Inherit",
      "From"
    ],
    [
      "val1",
      "val1",
      "val1",
      "val1",
      "val1",
      true,
      "val1"
    ],
    [
      "val2",
      "val2",
      "val2",
      "val2",
      "val2",
      true,
      "val2"
    ], 
    ...
]}
```

My final goal is to have a variable that contains the value of the key "values". I'm facing this issue :

> SyntaxError: Unterminated string in JSON at position 52428390

**EDIT :** the result is actually truncated, so the error message is relevant. There seems to be a limitation with the google spreashsheets api

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected values from `My final goal is to have a variable that contains the value of the key "values"`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output values you expect? By the way, from your error message, what is the total number of cells in your Google Spreadsheet? I'm worried that the number of cells might be large. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, request)` returns a Promise. You cannot immediately call JSON.parse like that. Either convert the outermost function to `async function` and use `await` or use `response.then(res => JSON.parse(res.getContextText()))`

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin sorry but for the second solution i get  ```TypeError: response.then is not a function```

Comment: @Tanaike I provided the sample of output i receive. The content of the key "values" in the response is what i want to add to a variable, but for the moment i can"t parse the result as JSON

Comment: I didn't know what `UrlFetchApp` is. Documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContentText(String)). Try doing `response.getContentText("UTF-8")`

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin i think you didn't get my point. I do receive the result in string. My problem is that i can"t parse it into JSON because it fails

Comment: I get your point, JSON.parse might not work either because the enconding is ASCII or else there is fauly encoding of a character like French characters etc. It is worth a try, read the docs.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin i did ```Logger.log(JSON.parse(response.getContentText("UTF-8")));``` and still same error unfortunately

Comment: I can't help but think there might be a more suitable approach to your problem than attempting to JSON.parse a 52MB+ response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked like there was a size limit with the api response, so it was returning a truncated response.